# Unable to login to Sqlplus as sysdba: "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"

Tags: sqlplus, sysdba

I can't login to sqlplus using:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

All the time, it gives me:

```
ERROR: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

If someone could help me, that would be awesome.

Comment: Before you connect, what do variables ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID,
    TWO_TASK and TNS_ADMIN show ?
    What OS do you run ?
    Is this the only database on the server/machine ?

Comment: See [**How to resolve sqlplus / as sysdba : ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/11/03/sqlplus-as-sysdba-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges/)

Comment: first do su - oracle

Answer (score 2):

When you login like `sqlplus / as sysdba` i'm under the impression you are saying *use the default login*, and *I do not want to enter a password*.
In a linux unix environment the ORACLE_SID must be set to a value:

```
export ORACLE_SID=xxxdb
```

If this is not enought, look at `sqlnet.ora` in `oracle_home/network/admin` and make sure you do NOT have
`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=NONE` (if you do -- you will get the `ora-01031`).